# How do I change the system language of a 2009 Chevrolet Cobalt?

Tags: chevrolet, cobalt, head-unit

How do I change the language of the system / head unit on a 2009 Chevrolet Cobalt?

Answer (score 1):

The below instructions are for the 2010 but they are very similar.

On the 09, I don't believe you need the ignition turned on to change the language.

On the left side of the steering wheel, info is the 3rd button from the top, reset is the first.

[image]

[image]

[image]